# javascript convert image path to file(list) object

Tags: javascript, image

I have a file upload that saves images as .png on the server and the link in a mysql database. To show thumbnails of the image before uploading I have a function that convertes the file list object to a preview pic. Now I want the user to edit the file selection later. For that I need to load the images from the server back as thumbnails. I think the best way to do this is to convert the file path stored in the database to a file object and apply this object to the function that creates the thumbnails  that I don't need to rewrite this function.
So my question is how can I convert my stored image links to a file list object?

**Edit:**

upload:

```
user selection -> file object -> base 64 -> blob -> display blob -> (maybe) edit -> upload selection as base 64 to server -> base 64 to .png -> save pic -> save link
```

later edit selection by user(how to do?):

```
saved link -> file object -> base 64 -> blob -> display blob -> (maybe) edit -> ...
```

***saved link -> file object*** How to do? Possible? Better way?
I hope it's now clearer to understand.

If someone has an idea how to do this or a better way please answer.

(I know that you should show Code when asking a question but I don't think that it is necesarry to upload the whole upload function here)

Comment: After uploading the file it's on the server and client can't access it directly. So you'll have to create a server side method like a web service (like the one for uploading) to serve this image.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. You are making a Content Management System? Why not create the thumbnails when the images are uploaded? Please rephrase and give more details in your question.

Comment: @11thdimension But how can I do this? The easiest way would be to create file object from image path and apply this to the javascript function (if that is possible).

Comment: @PHPglue Because I want that the user can remove some pics before uploading for example if he made a wrong selection

Comment: Keep a restricted folder on the Server. You still need to keep the images.

Comment: @PHPglue Why do you mean I need to keep the images. And isn't it the best way to let the user first complete his selection and upload than?

Comment: More details are needed to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You process is all frowned, so I may not answer correctly your question, but I'm pretty sure this is an X-Y problem.

Javascript `File` objects inherit from the `Blob` object.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) :

> A File object is a specific kind of a Blob, and can be used in any context that a Blob can.

**Never** convert a File to a base64 dataURL, if it's to convert it back to a Blob  ; this makes no sense and only pollute the browser's memory.

To display a Blob (or a File) in the browser, from media elements, or iframes, use the `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` method. This will return a blobURI, that will be available only for the life time of the initiating page, and only for the user's browsers. In case of user uploaded Files, the file is not even copied to memory, and the uri returned is just a direct pointer to the file on the user's system.

```js
inp.onchange = function(){
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
      document.body.appendChild(this);
    }
  img.onerror = function(){
      console.log('probably not a supported image file');
    }
  img.src = url;
  }
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

If you need to modify the image, you can do so by drawing the resulting image on a canvas.
Then, instead of exporting your canvas to a dataURI, directly use the [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method, which can [be polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill).

To send you File/Blob on your server, send the File/Blob directly instead of its 30% heavier base64 string representation.
This can be done really easily thanks to the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = done;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', theFile, fileName);
xhr.open('POST', yourServer);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Then you can retrieve it server side just like any File uploaded through the basic Multipart/Form method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But also your script requires a file object. For upload that is no problem but if I want to show the image as blob from a file path I need to convert the file path to a file object. Else Ican't show a file size for example, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "file path" ? Do you mean an url pointing to the file saved on server ? Then if you want to show it, well, you've got the url, just set an img's src to it. If you want to know its size, then it's probably better to make an XHR request with the [responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) set to "blob", or even to make a script server side that will just return the size of this file. If you're talking about something else, then please clarify.